# How to use Reverse Proxy for SSL with AppEngine and use Users service?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy on ec2 to provide secure access to my appengine app through a custom domain using nginx.  It seems to work fine, except when the pages require users service.  It redirects to the Google Accounts login, then goes to the appspot domain afterwards instead of my custom domain.  I'm aware that appengine has ssl in testing, but I'd like a solution I can use now.  Is it possible to overcome this or will I need to create my own users?

Following is my configuration:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name <custom-domain>;

  keepalive_timeout 70;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/cert/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/server.key;
  ssl_session_timeout  30m;

  location / {
      proxy_redirect   off;
      proxy_pass       https://<appid>.appspot.com;
      proxy_set_header Host <appid>.appspot.com;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_intercept_errors off;
  }
}
```

My domain has a CNAME pointing to ec2.

===

I found a workaround.  Still hoping for a simpler one and would appreciate feedback.

```
1) Client hits https: //mydomain.com/blah which goes through EC2 proxy https://appid.appspot.com/blah
2) The client is redirected to the google login page, with continue set as /aa?continue=/blah
3) Client logs into Google Accounts and is then redirected to https: //appid.appspot.com/aa?continue=/blah
4) Client hits https: //appid.appspot.com/aa which serves a redirect to https://mydomain.com/sc?c=ACSID&continue=/blah where ACSID is the Google account session cookie read by the handler for /aa.
5) Client hits https: //mydomain.com/sc?c=ACSID&continue=/blah which sets the ACSID session cookie for the domain mydomain.com and redirects to https: //mydomain.com/blah based on a continue parameter in aa passed to sc
```

Following is my web.xml

```
/ is publicly accessible
/aa is publicly accessible
/sc is publicly accessible
/* is restricted to logged in users
```

Following is the restriction in the handlers (with some tricky url escaping):

```
/ --> if not logged in, redirect to login page continue=/aa
/aa --> if not logged in, redirect to login page continue=/aa
/sc --> if not logged in, redirect to login page continue=/aa
/* --> if not logged in, redirect to login page continue=/aa?continue=*
```

After this, the user service seems to work normally even when going through a proxy serving with SSL.  The ACSID cookie is now on mydomain.com and sent through the proxy to appengine.

The appspot domain will still show up to tech savvy users, but this is not my main concern. My goal is to serve over https and keep my customdomain in the url bar and be more secure with user data as serving over no SSL using my custom domain.  Since the entire transaction is over https, I don't think this exposes the session cookie any more than using mydomain.com without SSL.  Any other cross site attacks would work even without this scheme anyway.

I'm still not sure why mydomain.com/_ah/conflogin?state=blah fails and requires this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround solved the problem for me -- thanks!

Here's the code I came up with, for anybody else stuck in the same situation. This is with some site-specific stuff pulled out, so may need a bit of tweaking to make it work. The cookie is SACSID because I'm using https; I think it would be ACSID for http.

```
class CompleteLoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        redirect_to=self.request.get('next', '/')
        if not redirect_to.startswith('/'): # don't allow redirects to another domain
            redirect_to = '/'
        session_id = self.request.get('SACSID', None)
        if session_id:
            self.response.set_cookie('SACSID', session_id)
        return self.redirect(redirect_to)

class PostLoginRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        domain = self.request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Host', None)
        if domain is None:
            # we are on the bare url; need to transfer the user -- and cookie
            sacsid = self.request.cookies.get('SACSID')
            next_url = config['domain'] + self.uri_for('complete_login', next=self.uri_for(route_name), SACSID=sacsid)
            return self.redirect(next_url)
        else:
            return self.redirect('/')
```

Here, PostLoginRedirectHandler is dealing with step (4), and CompleteLoginHandler is dealing with step (5) of tarun2000's description